# Faster Way to Count Colored Cells Using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a spreadsheet tab where the active range is A4:DD2500, so 270,000 cells.  I have code (thanks @EvilBlueMonkey) that populates the cells in Columns B to DD in a row blue, gray, or yellow based on the User's dropdown selection in Column A (see below).  When the User enters data into one of the blue cells it becomes green, signifying completion using conditional formatting.  I want to implement a code that runs dynamically after each time the User performs an entry that counts four different scenarios - blue cells, green cells, yellow cells without text, and yellow cells with text.  I've built the following code that will run but freezes Excel every time.  Is there any way that I can loop through 270,000 cells in a more efficient way?  If not, what about looping through rows that only have Column A populated?

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    
    'Declarations.
    Dim CountRange As Range
    Dim CountRangeCell As Range
    Dim BColorCounter As Long
    Dim GColorCounter As Long
    Dim YColorCounter As Long
    Dim YColorTextCounter As Long
        
    'SETTINGS:
    
    'Set Cells to be counted Range
    Set CountRange = Worksheets("ADIS").Range("B3:DD2500")
      
        'Loop through each cell in the range
        For Each CountRangeCell In CountRange
         'Checking Blue Color
        If Cells(CountRangeCell.Row, CountRangeCell.Column).DisplayFormat.Interior.Color = RGB(155, 194, 230) Then
        BColorCounter = BColorCounter + 1
        Else
               
        'Checking Yellow Color
        If Cells(CountRangeCell.Row, CountRangeCell.Column).DisplayFormat.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0) And CountRangeCell.Text = "" Then
        YColorCounter = YColorCounter + 1
        Else
       
        'Checking Green Color
        If Cells(CountRangeCell.Row, CountRangeCell.Column).DisplayFormat.Interior.Color = RGB(169, 208, 142) Then
        GColorCounter = GColorCounter + 1
        Else
        
        'Checking Yellow With Text
        If Cells(CountRangeCell.Row, CountRangeCell.Column).DisplayFormat.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0) And CountRangeCell.Value <> "" Then
        YColorTextCounter = YColorTextCounter + 1
           
        End If
        End If
        End If
        End If
        
        Next
        Range("C2504") = YColorCounter
        Range("D2504") = BColorCounter
        Range("E2504") = GColorCounter
        Range("F2504") = YColorTextCounter

End Sub
```

Thanks!
[image]

Comment: Read the cell color once, into a variable, and then do your checks

Comment: It looks strange to use such an event for what (I understood) you need. It should be a simple `Sub`, to be run once and memorize the colors count somewhere in a hidden sheet. Then use the `Worksheet_Change` event to only update the respective values **only for the changed cells**. The above comment idea will save many useless `If` statements and running on a range after hiding the empty rows (in A:A) using `SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)` will also help in terms of being faster. Each count can be kept in an array and its result to be dropped at once in the hidden sheet, at the code end.

Answer (score 2):

### A Worksheet Change: Count Highlighted Cells

[image]

- Note that this is a huge range and the code will take about 5 seconds (on each change in column `A`) if you remove the condition *"if the value in the first column of the range is blank, the row should not be counted"* i.e. if all cells in column `A` are populated.
- I consider all of it an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). The way to go would be implementing the logic by which you have used the conditional formatting in the first place, into VBA. But that requires much more information.

```vb
Option Explicit

' The worksheet name ("ADIS") is irrelevant. Use the 'Me' keyword instead.
' Whenever you change a value in the 1st column of the range,
' this code runs automatically counting the colors in the remaining columns.
' It is assumed that blank cells in the first column will have no highlights
' in the remaining columns.
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
     
    Const SHOW_MESSAGE_BOX As Boolean = True
    Dim Success As Boolean
    On Error GoTo ClearError

    Const SOURCE_RANGE As String = "A3:DD2500"

    Dim Blue As Long: Blue = RGB(155, 194, 230)
    Dim Green As Long: Green = RGB(169, 208, 142)
    Dim Yellow As Long: Yellow = RGB(255, 255, 0)
    
    Dim trg As Range, CountRange As Range

    With Me.Range(SOURCE_RANGE)
        Set trg = .Columns(1)
        ' If a change didn't happen in the first column, do nothing.
        If Intersect(trg, Target) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
        Set CountRange = .Resize(, .Columns.Count - 1).Offset(, 1)
    End With
    
    Dim CountRangeRow As Range, CountRangeCell As Range, r As Long
    Dim BlueCount As Long, GreenCount As Long
    Dim YellowCount As Long, YellowTextCount As Long
    
    For Each CountRangeRow In CountRange.Rows
        r = r + 1
        If Len(trg.Cells(r)) > 0 Then
            For Each CountRangeCell In CountRangeRow.Cells
                Select Case CountRangeCell.DisplayFormat.Interior.Color
                    Case Blue
                        BlueCount = BlueCount + 1
                    Case Green
                        GreenCount = GreenCount + 1
                    Case Yellow
                        If Len(CStr(CountRangeCell.Value)) = 0 Then ' is blank
                            YellowCount = YellowCount + 1
                        Else ' is not blank
                            YellowTextCount = YellowTextCount + 1
                        End If
                    'Case Else ' neither; do nothing
                End Select
            Next CountRangeCell
        End If
    Next CountRangeRow
    
    ' Before writing to the worksheet, disable events or the code
    ' gets triggered again and again until Excel crashes!
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    
    With Me
        .Range("C2504").Value = YellowCount
        .Range("D2504").Value = BlueCount
        .Range("E2504").Value = GreenCount
        .Range("F2504").Value = YellowTextCount
    End With

    Success = True

ProcExit:
    On Error Resume Next
        ' Don't forget to enable events again!
        If Not Application.EnableEvents Then Application.EnableEvents = True
        If SHOW_MESSAGE_BOX Then
            If Success Then MsgBox "Highlighted cells counted.", vbInformation
        End If
    On Error GoTo 0
    Exit Sub
ClearError:
    MsgBox "Run-time error '" & Err.Number & "':" & vbLf & vbLf _
         & Err.Description, vbCritical
    Resume ProcExit
End Sub
```